# Make mydomain.fr "mirror" to mydomain.com/france/

Tags: linux, alias, mirroring

**How do I "mirror"/point various specific domain names to a given `.com/suburl/`?**

*Examples:*

mydomain.fr > mymaindomain.com/france/

mydomain.se > mymaindomain.com/sweden/

*I currently have the following .conf setup:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName u13nuym
    ServerAlias u13nuym.somedomain.DK www.mydomain.com mydomain.com www.mydomain.dk mydomain.dk
    MaxClientsVHost 32
        <Directory />
                AAHatName u13nuym
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have taken care of pointing the various domain names with correct A-record to the server.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Is this topic more suitable at some other stackexchange site?

Answer (score -2):

Try to use .htacces

[HOW DO I REDIRECT MY SITE USING A .HTACCESS FILE](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain  
Redirect 302 / http://mt-example.com/
```

Comment: Don't use htaccess unless you have to it slows things down. Use  a directory block in the main config instead.